# Fans spin but CPU fan, LED are lit but no Display ("Ugly solution doesn't work anymore")

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios, power-supply

My PC most of the time doesn't start properly. As I turn it on, my fans start spinning (except CPU) and the LED's turn on but nothing else happens. At first this issue appeared like onece or twice a week. I've found a solution which worked out so I just stopped trieing to fix it after a month of resultless testing.
"Semi Solution":
I start my PC, and if the boot menu doesn't show up after 30 seconds, i just switch my PSU off for a split second and back on again. After that my PC would start just as any other PC would.
Problem:
I got a new PSU because my old PSU is to weak for my new 3070 and no my "Semi Solution" doesn't work anymore (I don't know the exact reason but I assume it doesn't allow a Voltage drop or something similar anymore).
I've tried:
-Checking wether everything is plugged in properly.
-Run a memorytest --> Doen't seem to be the problem
-Just upgraded my GPU and it's still the same problem.
-Reseting my bios
-experimented with diffrent methods to boot
-flashed my Bios and upgraded to V.2.7 (old 2.2)
-set the jumper to reset MB without booting
-Tested every RAM slot single, then 2X4 and at the end 2*8

If I use my old PSU I can still launch my PC with the "Semi Solution".

Im lost ;(
Help would really be appreciated form anyone :D

Specs:
PSU: (old) corsair cx600 (new) Gigabyte AP850GM
GPU: (old) Geforce GTX 1050Ti (new) Zotac RTX 3070 
Motherboard: AsRock z270 pro4
CPU: Core i7 7700k
RAM: Corsair Vengeance LPX 2x8GB
RAM: HyperX 2x4GB
Operating System: dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 / Windows 10

Comment: How old is the case?  What you describe sounds like the button to turn on the PC isn't properly working

Comment: Try to run the system outside of the cabinet with minimal components and see if the issue repeats. When you would switch OFF the PSU and then ON immediately and PC would start, would it start automatically without pressing power button on the cabinet? Re-seat all components including the CPU.

Comment: @Ramhound My case is around 6 Years old  Thx for reply

Comment: @patkin Already tried minimal components --> issue repeats
Yeah I need to make it almost shutdown but then power it again to make it start without using my Power Button

Comment: @patkin Is there an other way to reset the motherboard than Clearing with jumper or taking out the Batterie?
How do I reset CPU/RAM?
Thx for your reply

Comment: @Syntax3rror - You **reseat** not **reset** the CPU or RAM by uninstalling it and installing it.  However, I don't recommend you do that if you are not familiar with the process.

Comment: @patkin Ok thx well I just didn't know the word (I'm german)... I've reseated everything but the CPU --> Same result.
I don't have the motivation yet to unmount the CPU yet, i'll probably do it tomorrow or maybe Ill try another Case first

Comment: @everyone is there a way to fix my Switch or do I need to buy a new case to check wheter it's the switch or not?

Comment: Did you try running it outside of the cabinet? This requires you to take out motherboard from the cabinet (keep CPU & RAM mounted) and start it by shorting the pins where Power button wire from cabinet front panel plugs in to the board. Use a metallic object like a small screwdriver to short the pins for just one second or so. If the issue repeats, mostly there's nothing wrong with the power button on the cabinet. CPU fan not spinning but other cabinet fans spinning is a concern. If you have a Digital Multi meter check CPU fan header voltages.

Comment: @patkim Thx for the reply. I'm gonna test that with the Powerbutton tomorrow. I don't have a Multi meter, is there any other way of checking that? My CPU fan starts spinning after the quickswitch.

Comment: @patkin I tried running it outside the case --> same problem... Has anyone got any other idea? Thx for the reply

Comment: Then mostly it could be the Motherboard or the PSU having some fault. Since you tried another PSU may be mostly fault in board is a likely possibility. If board is under warranty, get it checked at the service center. Ideally a PC is not supposed switch on just by flipping the power switch. It starts when ATX PSU Pin 16 becomes active low which is what power button (or power pins shorting) does.

Comment: @patkim Thx for you effort i'm gonna try and replace my motherboard.

Comment: I suggest you first take it to a nearby service center or repair shop, they will have most of the spares and tools to nail down the faulty part. I can only speculate based on your observations and symptoms, can not ascertain.